# Laravel DB query throwing 'ErrorException: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string...'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I run the below query:

```
$this_application = \DB::table('applications')->where('application_id', '9650-9348-8494-8846')->first();
```

I get the following error:

```
 Next ErrorException: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /home/forge/default/resources/views/a_page.blade.php) in /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:466
Stack trace:
 #0 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(44): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 1)
 #1 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/forge/def...', Array)
```

What am I doing wrong? I can change the query or columns and I still get the same error. The hard coded ID was a replacement for the dynamic one that gets passed in, in case that was the issue.

The query is inside a controller.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with query it is about something you use in a_page.blade.php try `dd($this_application)` after this line. your problem in a view

Answer (score 0):

The error is associated with how you're displaying the data in the view `a_page.blade.php`. You must be trying to do something like `{{ $this_application }}`, instead use the properties that you fetch like `{{ $this_application->application_id }}`

We could help you better if you shared the view code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to print an array in a_page.blade.php with {{}} instead of array element. {{}} outputs string and not an array. try to output {{$this_application->application_id }} as @Sandeesh suggested